# In programming environments that have automatic memory management, how often are the OS memory allocation routines invoked at runtime?

Tags: memory, memory-management, garbage-collection, virtual-machine

Do implementations pre-allocate blocks of memory for objects using `malloc`? When these blocks are used up, will additional memory be requested? When garbage collection runs and compaction occurs, will memory be returned to the OS via calls to `free`?

Comment: The frequency does not really matter in itself. Imagine allocating memory only costs a single instruction, that'll be cheaper than whatever you're going to do with that memory. Generally application throughput relative to memory management overheads and latency are considered more important metrics than the raw call frequency of any such primitives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do implementations pre-allocate blocks of memory for objects using malloc?

Yes. Most often they pre-allocate continuous blocks of memory and implement they own allocation mechanism inside (for example based on *allocation pointer* - pointing the memory address for the next object so allocating an object is simply returning this address and moving this pointer by given amount of bytes). This is faster than relying on OS calls and gives better control of those memory regions. For example, in case of CLR on Windows, those blocks are called segments and are managed via VirtualAlloc/VirtualFree calls. First quite a big memory region is *reserved* and then more and more pages are being *committed* as they are needed. Malloc (or more general - HeapAPI in case of Windows) is not used in CLR.

> When these blocks are used up, will additional memory be requested?

Yes, they may be more blocks created but first they grow "inside" by committing (consuming) reserved memory.

> When garbage collection runs and compaction occurs, will memory be returned to the OS via calls to free?

It depends on specific runtime implementation but you should not look at it as a main memory reclamation mechanism. Compaction works inside those preallocated memory blocks - for example, allocation pointer will be moved back to the left after compaction occurred. But yes, in general, segments may be returned to OS when GC decides that it is no longer needed (like all objects living inside have been reclaimed). However, on 32-bit architectures with quite limited virtual memory space it could lead to unwanted memory fragmentation and reusing such memory block was a better option. On 64-bit this may not be so big problem, however, reusing those blocks still may be a just good idea.